How to SSH over a specific WiFi/ethernet connection?
I am using a Windows 10 PC with both WiFi connection and ethernet connection. The WiFi is connected to the Internet, while the ethernet is connected to an embedding device which has the IP of 172.16.0.x.
To be able to SSH login to the embedding device, I configured my ethernet connection as follow:

I use Windows 10 PowerShell to SSH login to the device, i.e.
ssh abc@172.16.0.x

I am only able to login to the device when I close the WiFi module on my PC.
How can I specify which connection to use when execute SSH login, so that I don't have to close my WiFi every time?

“How can I choose which connection to use when execute ssh login, so that I don't have to close my wifi everytime?” - In my experience unless you have two adapters that are connected to two subnets you shouldn’t have to or need to specify which adapter your using

@Ramhound Well, I'm not very familiar with networks, and not sure if there are "2 subnets / 2 adapters" in my situation. But it looks like the device is under a subnet(with an IP of 172.16.0.x). And I don't know why I must close the wifi module when  ssh into it.

@Lionnel104 What's the IP and netmask configured on WiFi adapter? If the WiFi network happens to use the same IP subnet (172.16.0.0/24) as the Ethernet one, then certainly it would be problematic.

@TomYan The WIFI adapter has access to the public Internet and is configured to automatically get its IP and netmask. Its IP is 10.68.x.x
